# How to make a modal dialog with Angular2 (beta 17) and MDL?

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, material-design, material-design-lite

I am trying to find some examples on how to do a Confirmation modal dialog in Angular 2.0 (beta version: 17) with Material design Lite (mdl).

Thanks !

Comment: I tried with this tutorial: http://koscielniak.me/post/2016/03/angular2-confirm-dialog-component/                                                


but i'm getting this error: 




angular2.dev.js:25644 TypeError: this._confirmService.activate is not a function
    at Login.showConfirmDialog (http://localhost:3000/dist/components/login/login.component.js:59:42)

Comment: if you haven't found a solution: http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl/dialogs